# Как работает покупка ip адреса

Tags: сеть, ip, tcp-ip

Этот вопрос больше связан с тем, как сервер подтверждает твой ip адрес.

Допустим есть провайдер domru, он купил ip адреса.
Почему они просто не могут использовать чужой ip адрес без покупки?

Мне хочется понять, как сервер подтверждает что ip 5.23.162.54 - это мой ip. Он передаётся вместе с пакетом данных?
Или используется сторонний сервер, который говорит что это мой ip?

Comment: Я знаю, что можно указать обратный ip адрес. И тогда сервер посчитает тебя за другого и отправит ответ на ip, который ты указал. Можно ли авторизовать себя в сети под произвольным адресом и принять на него пакет

Comment: прописать в настройки можно все что угодно (ну почти), но вот только кто доставит пакет такому серверу?

Comment: Короткий ответ - потому что пакеты на чужие адреса к ним не пойдут. Длинный, нудный и непонятный - почитайте про роль RIR (в частности, [RIPE NCC](https://ripe.net)) и [BGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol) в функционировании интернетов.